# The correct usage of unlikely macro in multiple conditions

Tags: c++, c, performance, likely-unlikely

I see many examples using the `unlikely` macro (not the C++20 attribute) as `if( unlikely( server == 0 ) )`, but never combining them both as `if( unlikely( server == 0 ) || unlikely( client == 0 ) )` or `if( unlikely( server == 0 || client == 0 ) )`.

Can I need to use two `unlikely` on two conditionals for the same if or the `unlikely` is interpreted correctly if used only once in the whole if condition as in `if( unlikely( server == 0 || client == 0 ) )`?

Other questions about unlikely:

1. [gcc likely unlikely macro usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922607/gcc-likely-unlikely-macro-usage)
2. [efficient, extremely-unlikely conditionals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217933/efficient-extremely-unlikely-conditionals)
3. [likely and unlikely macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973091/likely-and-unlikely-macros)
4. [likely/unlikely instead of if/else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791728/likely-unlikely-instead-of-if-else)

Comment: unlikely applies to the condition as a whole, thats why I dont really understand your worries. Why does it matter how to correctly place it on two parts of the conditions, when it only matters that its on that branch?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Where does the documentation say `unlikely` applies to “the condition as a whole”?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The `||` is short-circuiting, so there might be a "hidden" branch in it as well, that might be likely or unlikely.

Comment: @EricPostpishil I think I confused it with the C++ likely/unlikely, which as I understand does apply to the branch taken. Anyhow, I was wrong.